# I have been vs I am

Tags: tense

Is it possible to use "is / were etc" in the same context as "Has been"

Here are some examples...

> He has been taking drugs.
> He is taking drugs.

Could the second example be used in the same context as the first?

> He has been training hard at the gym.
> He is training hard at the gym.

Could the second example be used in the same context as the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Has been" means the past up to, *but not necessarily including*, the present.

"He has been taking drugs," might mean once a week, but not necessarily today.

"Is" means the present, i.e., *right now*, and doesn't preclude past, but does not, in itself, include it.

*He is taking drugs," implies he is currently using them.